# Windows SBS 2008 domain, Outlook 2007 calendar sharing / appointments not synced

Tags: windows-server-2008, outlook, outlook-2007, calendar

A user on this network reports not being able to delete appointments on Outlook 2007 calendars that are shared (not delegated) with other users in the domain. Specifically, the delete appears to work, but after 5 seconds or so the appointment re-appears. Permissions seem fine. 
Problem does not occur with other users because they do not share calendars.

Is this behaviour intended (appointments re-appearing after they have been deleted)?

Comment: This may be due to the permission setting on the calendar being shared (after all). The delete permission was set to 'Own' rather than 'All'. The question still remains however, because, as a user, I was technically still able to delete the item from their calendar, only to have it appear seconds later. So why does this permission level even exist?